# Is O(|V| * k) equal to O(|E|)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, complexity-theory

I assume that when representing adjacency lists, we need to iterate over all the vertices and their neighbors, so the time complexity to build an adjacency list is O(|V| * k) where V is the set of vertices and k is the number of neighbors a certain vertex has (k = |V| - 1 if the graph is complete). However, every resource I've encountered states that the time complexity to build an adjacency list is O(|E|) where E is the set of edges.

Since we are considering the worst case, the worst case of a graph is a connected one, where |E| is equal to (|V| 2) = (|V| * (|V|-1))/2. As mentioned above, building an adjacency list from a complete graph requires iterating over all the vertices and their neighbors. The time complexity of this operation will be |V| * k where k is |V|-1. So, it should be O(|V| * (|V|-1)) => O(|V|^2).
Since we found that the number of edges is (V * (V-1)) / 2 => O(|V|^2), then the two complexities, O(|V| * k) and O(|E|) should be the same.

The thing that confuses me is why people prefer to use O(|E|) instead of O(|V| * k)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is O(|V| * k) equal to O(|E|)?

Yes.

> where V is the set of vertices and k is the number of neighbors a certain vertex has

This definition is incorrect since `k` depends on *"the certain vertex"*` so you would need to define it as the max-degree (maximal number of edges a vertex has) in order to have a usable definition.

---

On the note of *max-degree*, `O(maxdeg * |V|)` is not equals to `O(|E|)`. The max-degree is a worse approximation of the complexity than `|E|`.

Just imagine a graph with a single vertex that has `1_000` edges but every other vertex only has `1` edge.

But since Big-O only defines upper-bounds, the algorithm is of course still in `O(maxdeg * |V|)`.

---

In any case, you will maximally look once at each edge in the graph, so `|E|`. And the amount of edges is the sum of all outgoing edges of all vertices, i.e. what you tried to formulate with `|V| * k`. So both are absolutely identical. I.e.

```
|E| = sum (v * outdegree(v))
```

(`k` is not the maxdegree in this case but the outdegree specific to each `v`)

> The thing that confuses me is why people prefer to use O(|E|) instead of O(|V| * k)?

In general, it is just much more common to view a graph as an entity that has vertices and edges, with operations being dependent on `V` and `E`. It is much simpler to just say `O(|E|)` than to overcomplicate things by looking at it from an *"vertices and their outgoing edges"*-angle.

Comment: If you define k as the max degree, there are graphs where k*|V| grows faster (quadratic) than |E| (linear)

Comment: So the reason why people prefer to use O(|E|) is because of convenience. What I meant from `k` is the maximum degree for a vertex, which in the case of a complete graph, it is (n-1). Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Henry Thats correct. But dont forget that `O(...)` defines an upper-bound. So the claim still holds. But sure, the estimation of the Big-O class is worse then.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking no. O(|V| * k) equal to O(|E|) is not true if k is the max degree. It would hold if k is the average degree.

Comment: @Henry That is what I meant, sorry if that was not clear. I.e. `algorithm \in O(|E|) \subset O(|V| * k)`. Which follows that `algorithm \in O(|V| * k)` as well.